# grid.arrange shows empty plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created some plots using `ggplot2` in R. Now, I want to combine two plots using `grid.arrange`, however after I use this function I get only empty plots.

I also tried `cowplot` library but I am getting same problem.

```
## Pipe age distribution in the initial pipe network conditions
pipe_age_0 = 2019 + net.ini$time.construction
pipe_age = 2019 - pipe_age_0

p6 <- ggplot(net.ini, aes(x = pipe_age))
p6 + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1,
                    col="black",
                    size=0.1,
                    fill = "lightgrey") +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 140, by = 10)) +
     labs(y="Count", x="Age [Years]") +
     theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "")

## Density stacked with histogram count
p7 <- ggplot(net.ini, aes(x = pipe_age))
p7 + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                    binwidth = 1,
                    col="black",
                    size=0.1,
                    fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1, fill="#FF6666") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 140, by = 10)) +
  labs(y="Density", x="Age [Years]") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "")

grid.arrange(p6, p7)
```

I expect to have two graphs one above another, or one beside another using `grid.arrange`. However for some reason I keep getting empty plot. This is how plots p6 and p7 look like, and third one with `grid.arrange`, the empty plot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Try to define `pipe_age` (and `pipe_age0`) as variable of your data frame, i.e. `net_ini$pipe_age_0 = 2019 + net.ini$time.construction` and `net_ini$pipe_age = 2019 - net.ini$pipe_age_0`!

Comment: Hi everyone, and thanks for giving me good advice. I decided to upload my work on google drive, and here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xeuD_6DNW1TkjVGCOdz2RjEqtFVw30-x/view?usp=sharing) so you can download it, try to run it on your computer and figure out what could be a problem, if you are still interested. I'm new to R, programming in general, second month to be honest, and still learning a lot. Cheers ;D

Comment: @Na5H, it's bad practice to ask people to download files to reproduce. There could be malicious code or at the least it's much more inconvenient than making a minimal example. One of the benefits of creating a minimal example is you often find out what was going wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why, but it works only after we have assigned it back to the variable. Didn't work when I used the simple

```
p <- ggplot(df)
p + geom_col(aes(x,y))
```

So try something like this:

```
p7 <- ggplot(net.ini, aes(x = pipe_age))
p7 <- p7 + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                    binwidth = 1,
                    col="black",
                    size=0.1,
                    fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1, fill="#FF6666") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 140, by = 10)) +
  labs(y="Density", x="Age [Years]") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "")
```

Works for both `cowplot` and `grid.arrange`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. And I know you asked this 4 years ago, but I'll share what helped me just in case other people still experience something similar.

The only thing that helped me fix the empty plot problem was adjusting the code I wrote to create the plots. Instead of making the ggplot line its own line, combine with the lines below that include the specifications for the plot. For example, your p6 plot should look like this:

```
p6 <- ggplot(net.ini, aes(x = pipe_age)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1,
                    col="black",
                    size=0.1,
                    fill = "lightgrey") +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 140, by = 10)) +
     labs(y="Count", x="Age [Years]") +
     theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "")
```

As you can see the only difference is that I deleted the 2nd "p6" and added a plus symbol to connect the lines together. After I did this with my own assignment, it worked.